# Handling whitelabelling with Webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm the maintainer of a web app built with angular and webpack. I've been tasked with making the web app whitelabel capable. In practice, this means that the app will need a different appearance (css/images) and configuration for each customer.

I'm struggling with finding a good solution that doesn't devolve into an unmaintainable mess.

Does anyone else have any experience building whitelabel capable web apps using webpack? What methodology was used?

Answer (score 0):

If you control your webpack build via a runner like `gulp` you can alter the config on the fly based upon args or environment vars. This would allow you to use an alias which can be overridden with a different path for the CSS / assets etc

For example

In webpack.config.js add aliases for the paths that will change per build, with some default paths

```js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets')
    'css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'css')
  }
}
```

In your CSS use the alias instead of hardcoded path (`~` means treat as module path, webpack will look for an alias)

```css
@import '~css/some/other/styles.css'

.blah { 
  background: url('~assets/blah.img')
}
```

In a gulp file, change the path the aliases point to at build time

```js
import webpack from 'webpack'
import {argv} from 'yargs'
import gutil from 'gulp-util'
import webpackConfig from './webpack.config.js'

gulp.task('webpack', (cb) => {
  // clone the original config for safe local manipulation
  const wpConfig = Object.create(webpackConfig)

  if (argv.css) wpConfig.resolve.alias.css = argv.css
  if (argv.assets) wpConfig.resolve.alias.assets = argv.assets

  return webpack(wpConfig, (err, stats) => {
    if (err) throw new gutil.PluginError('[webpack]', err)

    gutil.log('[webpack]', stats.toString({ colors: true }))

    cb()
  })
})
```

And run it via command line passing overridden paths `gulp webpack --css client1/css --assets client1/assets`